# Combine dynamic records in an MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

My company uses a barcode scanner to scan computers in rooms for inventory purposes.  We scan a barcode on the door of the room and then scan a barcode on each computer.

I have created my own Access database that imports the records and then let us track our computers in each room and track additional non-inventory information about them - like type of computer (computer lab or Admin computer), date it was moved to another room, who the computer belongs to if it is an admin computer, etc.  I would now like to scan each computer twice - one scan for the inventory code and one scan for the Dell Service Tag barcode.

I end up with a table that looks like this:

```
03/14/18,15:00:15,03,117SE
03/14/18,15:00:23,01,Z0820167
03/14/18,15:00:27,01,9MR8S52
03/14/18,15:00:34,01,Z0820168
03/14/18,15:00:39,01,9MQMS52
03/14/18,15:00:47,01,Z0820148
03/14/18,15:00:54,01,C6RLS52
03/14/18,15:02:29,01,Z0820138
03/14/18,15:02:32,01,C6RMS52
```

The 03 record is the room number scan from the barcode on the door
The 01 records alternate:
The first row is the Inventory Tag that starts with the Z
The next row is the Dell Service tag which varies.
The rows then continue on to the subsequent computers

I would like to combine the Inventory tag record and the Dell service tag record into one record for each computer.  I can figure out the logic to determine what kind of record each record is (inventory or service tag) but I am unsure of:

1. How to take the inventory code from 1 record
2. Then take the same field from the second record that has the Service tag
3. Combine the records putting the dell service tag in a new field
4. Then moving onto the next set of records until the end of the table

I would like to end up with a table something like this:

```
Date         Time        Room       Inventorytag       Servicetag
03/14/18     15:00:15    117SE       Z0820167           9MR8S52
03/14/18     15:00:34    117SE       Z0820168           9MQMS52
03/14/18     15:00:47    117SE       Z0820148           C6RLS52
03/14/18     15:02:29    117SE       Z0820138           C6RMS52
```

I am limited by our corporate inventory guys on how the scanner is configured I can change the data format.  I will import the data remove the dellservice tag records and then output the txt file in the format that they need for the inventory system.

So far I have done all of my data manipulation using VBA and SQL queries.

So I want to make this work. Any ideas!!

Comment: Use a loop and the VBA split function - when you come back with some sample code there'll be lots of help waiting for you

Comment: @dbmitch I assume that the split function that you are suggesting is to split the delimited file but I think the split is not needed because I am importing the comma delimited file into a table so the fields are split out of the delimited file for me.

Comment: @dbmitchThe problem is that the inventory tag field contains both an inventory tag and then on the next record it contains the service tag because the scanner is not sophisticated enough to recognize the difference in the two.   I am using a loop to read through the records.   

What I don't know is how to store the inventory tag from record 1 and then make sure the next row has a service tag then take the two and create a new record in the same table (preferably)  and remove the two records that I retrieved the data from.